# How to fix error: 800704CF "Your password has expired. First, change it on the web, then come back..."

Tags: microsoft-account

I'm trying to sync my Windows Phone 8 with my outlook account and am getting the following error message:

```
Hotmail Error

Last updated 2 seconds ago

Your password has expired. First, change it on the web, then come back and update it in your account on the phone.

Last tried 2 seconds ago
Error code: 800704CF
```

I tried changing by outlook.com account and it made no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This happened to me when I didn't have a SIM card in my phone. Turned out it is caused by the time being wrong on the phone, as the phone was not able to get the correct time off the mobile phone network.

1. Go to **Settings** → **date+time**
2. Switch **Set Automatically** to **off**
3. Enter the correct date and time

Go back and try syncing with your Microsoft account again.

Comment: it didn't solved my problem..! any other work around..?