# i'm trying to sync my windows phone 8.1 but i'm getting the following error

Tags: 8.1

We can't synchronise at the moment. But you may be able to find this error code more at www.windowsphone.com

Last tried 3sec ago
Error:800704cf

Comment: Could you provide additional details. Looks like this is a error that appears when you try to sync email. Please mention what provider you are using for email (gmail, outlook, corporate exchange, etc). If you have been able to sync previously. If you tried with both cellular data and wifi. Did you change your password recently? Etc.

Comment: Also pls see this question that may be related:
http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/6178/how-to-fix-error-800704cf-your-password-has-expired-first-change-it-on-the-w

Answer (score 1):

It might be a storage problem error. My son had same problems with his Nokia Lumia 630. I did a quick backup - saved Music, photos and videos with the Windows Phone App and then ran the Lumia software recovery tool. Lost nothing and his phone works a lika a treat now - better than before.