# how to solve code error 800704CF

Tags: 8.0, store, error

I cant download any applications I even kept on making new Microsoft account but still I can't download everytime it show error code

Comment: Is this a Windows phone or PC?

Answer (score 3):

The error 800704CF generally occurs when the server is not in sync with your device. This can occur due to improper network connectivity or improper date and time.

Some common solutions are :

- Set correct date and time manually
- Try connecting via WI-Fi
- Set install location of apps to Phone storage
- Remove your SIM card and re-insert it.

The most common solution is to delete and add your MS account again. But since it didn't work for you I am saying it at last.

References :

- [Error code: 800704CF while installing own app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880453/5407188)
- [Error code: 800704CF on Hotmail - Stackexchange](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/6178/18061)
- [Error code: 800704CF while syncing device - Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdupdate/sync-error-code-800704cf/d2c6f42d-8b39-47ca-abb1-f406332fd494)
- [Error code: 800704CF in Email settings - Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdtips/error-code-800704cf/a431e0d4-7d7c-48da-ba1e-e93f17d44711)
- [Error code: 800704CF while refreshing - Microsoft community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/mobiledevices/forum/mdlumia-mdtips/what-means-error-code-800704cf-when-asking-to/b2753fd7-0ad7-4ea2-afb8-2781363a3548)